# Troubleshooting 5.5.0 smtp; 503 Bad sequence of commands (Microsoft SMTP + Exchange 2003)

Tags: exchange-2003, smtp

### Note: this question has changed.  Originally I believed it had something to do with BDAT.

An external party is trying to send us a message to a valid address and they're getting an NDR:

```
<sender.it #5.5.0 smtp;503 Bad sequence of commands>
```

Note that this message is coming from the sender's side.

I'm looking at my SMTP logs and am finding:

```
#Fields: date time c-ip cs-username cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query sc-status sc-win32-status sc-bytes cs-bytes
2009-11-24 19:38:26 85.88.193.3 sender.it RCPT - +TO:+<me@mydomain.com> 250 0 0 28
2009-11-24 19:38:26 85.88.193.3 sender.it BDAT - - 250 0 0 9
2009-11-24 19:38:26 85.88.193.3 sender.it BDAT - - 250 0 42 9
2009-11-24 19:38:26 85.88.193.3 sender.it BDAT - - 250 0 42 9
2009-11-24 19:38:26 85.88.193.3 sender.it QUIT - sender.it 240 11188 0 37
```

The message never reaches Exchange.  No record of anything from the sender in the message tracking log. I'm also running GFI MailEssentials 14 and there is no record of this message in its logs.  No Exchange-related errors or warning in the event logs.  Queues are normal.

Where do I go from here?  This user is not able to send mail to my domain.  I'm not having any other reported incoming email issues at this time...everything seems to be flowing like normal.

Comment: I had a similar issue and found that our TrendMicro was quarantining the message right after the SMTP accepted it. By doing this, the Message Tracking didn't see it as well. Maybe you have a 3rd party software that is doing some sort of policy checking - profanity, credit card, etc. It also may have had a file type set up to quarantine.

Answer (score 2):

If the server responds to the ehlo command and lists Chunking, then it supports BDAT. To test your server, telnet to it on port 25 and issue the ehlo command. It will then list which of the ESMTP commands that it supports. If Chunking is in the list then BDAT is not the problem. Because this is Exchange you should see that it supports the full ESMTP command set and Chunking because AFAIK, this is the default for Exchange.

Your log file doesn't have enought info to tell what the problem is. You need to modify the log file parameters to include status codes so that you can see what the status is for each command (log file entry) and determine what the problem is.

Comment: Good suggestion.  I believe I may have jumped the gun thinking it had something to do with BDAT.  I've enabled status codes in my logs and will have the user resend.

Comment: I edited my question to include new log entries.  Everything looks like it's succeeding.  However, the message doesn't seem to get any further than the SMTP server.

Comment: Yep, based on the logs it looks like it's making it into SMTP and past the SMTP filtering (if you have any enabled). My next suggestion would be to use the Message Tracking tool to see if it's getting filtered by the Intelligent Message Filter.

Comment: No record of the message in Exchange.  I have a spam filter integrated into Exchange and it's not showing this message coming in either.  I'll keep digging.

Comment: Check the badmail folder on the Exchange server to see if the message is in there. If it is then it means that the sender is being filtered by Sender Filtering.

Comment: At this point I would start eliminating things. Can you temporarily eliminate GFI from the equation? Then, the next step would be to disable the various SMTP filters (located in Global Settings>Message Delivery) and see if the email comes through. If it does, then re-enable them one at a time, sending a test email each time until it stopes working again. When it does then you'll know that the last filter you enabled is the cause. Not to worry about opening yourself to any risk, the filters control spam only and not relaying, etc.

Comment: Good ideas, but I'm not sure if I can demand that much participation by the sender.  Bad mail folder is empty.  BTW, I updated the question with the error message he's getting in the NDR.

Comment: That's a strange ndr and a strange problem because based on your logs your server is receiving the message. The 250 status codes mean success and the 240 status code is the normal status code for ending the smtp session after the message has been received. the ndr doesn't correlate to the logs. i'm at a loss to think of anything else except to try and rule things out as suggested in my earlier comment. if you can manage to get some cooperation from the sender then follow my suggestions and see where it leads. keep us posted on your progress and if i think of anything else, i'll post back.

Answer (score 1):

The [Exchange Best Practices Analyzer](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=dbab201f-4bee-4943-ac22-e2ddbd258df3&displaylang=en) will check to see if the server supports BDAT (their writeup on this particular test can be found here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997593.aspx).  Not sure if disabling the CHUNKING and BINARYMIME verbs will help, but if you want to try it for purposes of receiving that particular e-mail from the Italian provider, instructions are here: http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=257569